# Make WooCommerce checkout shipping fields visible and remove "Ship to different address?" checkbox

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout

I am wondering if there is a way to remove the checkbox "Ship to a different address?" in woocommerce checkout page, but keep the shipping fields visible. I have tried:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_needs_shipping_address', '__return_false');
```

It works, however it won't show any field in the "shipping field tab".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the shipping address fields to always be visible you can use **CSS**.

Try adding these lines to your **active theme's stylesheet**:

```
/* hides the checkbox */
#ship-to-different-address-checkbox {
    display:none;
}

/* disable touch event or mouse click */
#ship-to-different-address label {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

If you want you can translate the text *Ship to a different address?* using any translation plugin. For example **Polylang** or **Loco Translate**.

Answer (score 0):

Administration->Woocommerce->Settings->Shipping->Shipping Options